# reversed condition with different outcome

Tags: python, list, operator-keyword

'''

```
import operator
def sorted (a, xs):
   '''a is the operator, xs is a list''' 
  if a == operator.gt:
       for i in range(len(xs)):
           if xs[i] < xs[i+1]:
               return False
           else: True
```

'''

if i write it in reversed condition, error comes out **"IndexError: list index out of range"**

```
 if a == operator.gt:
   for i in range(len(xs)):
       if xs[i] > xs[i+1]:
           return True
       else: False
```

Comment: Please provide the example of variable that was used. Though my guess is that in the first case, you encounter the condition before the end of the list, and you don't in the second case.

Comment: sorted (operator.gt, [2, 2, 4, 5, 8, 9]), it works on the first code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that you wrote `for i in range(len(xs)):` and then tried to access `xs[i+1]`. This is bound to raise an exception `IndexError: list index out of range` in the last iteration of the loop.

A second issue with your code is the `else: True` or `else: False` part, which does nothing. Your probably forgot the keyword `return`. As it stands, your code is equivalent to this:

```py
import operator
def sorted (a, xs):
   '''a is the operator, xs is a list''' 
  if a == operator.gt:
       for i in range(len(xs)):
           if xs[i] < xs[i+1]:
               return False
```

The exception will be raised in the last iteration of the loop, when `i == len(xs)-1` and `i+1` is 1 too large.

Whether or not you will get the exception `IndexError: list index out of range` depends on whether the `for`-loop gets a chance to proceed to its last iteration, or whether the function will `return` before the last iteration of the `for`-loop.

Another issue is that you called your function `sorted`, which is already the name of a builtin function in python. Reusing that name will cause confusion and possible errors. Since your function does not return a sorted list, but instead tests whether a list is sorted, I recommend calling it `is_sorted` instead.

To fix both issues at once:

- remove the `else` branch;
- add `return True` **on the same level of indention as the `for` keyword**;
- replace `range(len(xs))` with `range(len(xs)-1)`.

Do you understand the need for `-1` here? Imagine if your list has 3 elements. How many comparisons do you need to check whether it is sorted? You need to compare the first element with the second; then the second with the third; and that's it. Only 2 comparisons for 3 elements. If you omit the `-1`, you would be trying to compare the third element with an imaginary fourth element, and the python interpreter complains and raises `IndexError: list index out of range`.

Final code:

```py
import operator
def is_sorted (a, xs):
   '''a is the operator, xs is a list''' 
  if a == operator.gt:
       for i in range(len(xs)-1):
           if xs[i] < xs[i+1]:
               return False
       return True
```

### Following python conventions: optional argument `reverse`

Comparing argument `a` with `operator.gt` is a bit clumsy, since your function as it is written doesn't work with a custom operator anyway. I suggest following the conventions for [python builtins `sorted` and `list.sort()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted), which use an optional argument `reverse` defaulting to `False`.

Code:

```py
def is_sorted(xs, reverse=False):
  if not reverse:
    for i in range(len(xs)-1):
      if xs[i] > xs[i+1]:
        return False
    return True
  else:
    for i in range(len(xs)-1):
      if xs[i] < xs[i+1]:
        return False
    return True
```

Further improvement suggestions:

- add optional argument `key` like python builtins `sorted` and `list.sort`;
- let the user give you a comparison operator, and use that operator directly instead of `<` or `>`

### Alternative code using [`any` or `all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all)

```py
def is_sorted(xs):
  return all(xs[i] <= xs[i+1] for i in range(len(xs)-1))

def is_sorted(xs):
  return not any(xs[i] > xs[i+1] for i in range(len(xs)-1))
```

Comment: however is_sorted (operator.gt, [2, 2, 4, 5, 8, 9]) returns True which is not right

Comment: @SummerPan I just tested it and it returns False. Which version are you talking about?

Comment: now it works, thanks a lot, i'll just focus on the first version for now.

Comment: @SummerPan Note that if `a` is an operator such as `operator.lt`, then you can write `a(x,y)` instead of `x < y`. I strongly advise you not to write `if a == operator.gt`.